# Has Mesa dropped support for HW acceleration on very old GPUs?

Tags: hardware

Today I've tried launching Kubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP OmniBook XE3 with S3 Savage IX-MV video chip only to find out this:

```
$ glxinfo|egrep 'renderer|direct'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on softpipe
$ grep '(EE)' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown
$ grep 'SAVAGE(' /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -vE 'Chose mode|Not using|No suitable BIOS mode found for|\[junkers\]'
[   340.560] (II) SAVAGE(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
[   340.560] (++) SAVAGE(0): Depth 16, (--) framebuffer bpp 16
[   340.560] (==) SAVAGE(0): RGB weight 565
[   340.560] (==) SAVAGE(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   340.560] (II) SAVAGE(0): vgaHWGetIOBase: hwp->IOBase is 0x03d0, hwp->PIOOffset is 0x0000
[   340.560] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using XAA acceleration architecture
[   340.560] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using HW cursor
[   340.560] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using video BIOS to set modes
[   340.578] (II) SAVAGE(0): initializing int10
[   340.584] (II) SAVAGE(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[   340.585] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA BIOS detected
[   340.585] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE Version 2.0
[   340.585] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 8192 kB
[   340.585] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM: S3 Incorporated. M7 BIOS
[   340.585] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
[   340.586] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: S3 Incorporated.
[   340.586] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: VBE 2.0
[   340.586] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Rev 1.1
[   340.586] (--) SAVAGE(0): Chip: id 8c12, "Savage/IX-MV"
[   340.586] (--) SAVAGE(0): Engine: "MobileSavage"
[   340.586] (--) SAVAGE(0): AGP card detected
[   340.586] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using BusType PCI by default
[   340.587] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using PCI DMA
[   340.587] (II) SAVAGE(0): Savage3D/MX/IX does not support command DMA.
[   340.587] (==) SAVAGE(0): Will try only vertex DMA mode
[   340.625] (==) SAVAGE(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   340.625] (--) SAVAGE(0): probed videoram:  8192k
[   341.586] (--) SAVAGE(0): No DDC signal
[   341.587] (II) SAVAGE(0): I2C bus "I2C bus" initialized.
[   341.587] (II) SAVAGE(0): I2C device "I2C bus:ddc2" registered at address 0xA0.
[   341.593] (--) SAVAGE(0): Detected current MCLK value of 83.045 MHz
[   341.593] (--) SAVAGE(0): 1024x768 TFT LCD panel detected and active
[   341.593] (--) SAVAGE(0): - Limiting video mode to 1024x768
[   341.653] (--) SAVAGE(0): Found 13 modes at this depth:
[   341.656] (II) SAVAGE(0): Monitor0: Using hsync range of 31.50-47.82 kHz
[   341.656] (II) SAVAGE(0): Monitor0: Using vrefresh range of 56.00-59.92 Hz
[   341.656] (II) SAVAGE(0): Monitor0: Using maximum pixel clock of 63.50 MHz
[   341.656] (II) SAVAGE(0): Estimated virtual size for aspect ratio 1.3333 is 1024x768
[   341.656] (II) SAVAGE(0): Clock range:  10.00 to 250.00 MHz
[   341.666] (--) SAVAGE(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[   341.666] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Driver mode "1024x768": 56.0 MHz, 47.3 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[   341.666] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "1024x768"x59.9   56.00  1024 1072 1104 1184  768 771 775 790 +hsync -vsync (47.3 kHz)
[   341.666] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "800x600": 40.0 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 60.3 Hz
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[   341.667] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "800x600": 36.0 MHz, 35.2 kHz, 56.2 Hz
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz)
[   341.667] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "640x480": 25.2 MHz, 31.5 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[   341.667] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "400x300": 20.0 MHz, 37.9 kHz, 60.3 Hz (D)
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "400x300"x60.3   20.00  400 420 484 528  300 300 302 314 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[   341.667] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "400x300": 18.0 MHz, 35.2 kHz, 56.3 Hz (D)
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "400x300"x56.3   18.00  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz)
[   341.667] (**) SAVAGE(0): *Default mode "320x240": 12.6 MHz, 31.5 kHz, 60.1 Hz (D)
[   341.667] (II) SAVAGE(0): Modeline "320x240"x60.1   12.59  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[   341.667] (==) SAVAGE(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   341.674] (II) SAVAGE(0): initializing int10
[   341.675] (II) SAVAGE(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[   341.676] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA BIOS detected
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE Version 2.0
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 8192 kB
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM: S3 Incorporated. M7 BIOS
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: S3 Incorporated.
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: VBE 2.0
[   341.677] (II) SAVAGE(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Rev 1.1
[   341.784] (II) SAVAGE(0): 4740 kB of Videoram needed for 3D; 8192 kB of Videoram available
[   341.784] (II) SAVAGE(0): Sufficient Videoram available for 3D
[   341.784] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] bpp: 16 depth: 16
[   341.784] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Sarea 2200+284: 2484
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Using the DRM lock SAREA also for drawables.
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] framebuffer handle = 0xf0000000
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] added 1 reserved context for kernel
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): X context handle = 0x1
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] installed DRM signal handler
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] aperture handle = 0xf2000000
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Enabling ShadowStatus for DRI.
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Status handle = 0x0b388000
[   342.869] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Status page mapped at 0xb77c7000
[   342.894] (II) SAVAGE(0): [drm] Added 32 65536 byte DMA buffers
[   342.895] (II) SAVAGE(0): [dri] visual configs initialized
[   342.895] (**) SAVAGE(0): DRI is enabled
[   343.670] (II) SAVAGE(0): virtualX:1024,virtualY:768
[   343.670] (II) SAVAGE(0): bpp:16,tiledwidthBytes:2048,tiledBufferSize:1572864 
[   343.670] (II) SAVAGE(0): bpp:16,widthBytes:2048,BufferSize:1572864 
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): videoRambytes:0x00800000 
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): textureSize:0x0015f000 
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): textureSize:0x0015f000 
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): textureOffset:0x00680000 
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): depthOffset:0x00500000,depthPitch:2048
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): backOffset:0x00380000,backPitch:2048
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): Reserved back buffer at offset 0x380000
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): Reserved depth buffer at offset 0x500000
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): Reserved 1404 kb for textures at offset 0x680000
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): Using 1023 lines for offscreen memory.
[   343.671] (II) SAVAGE(0): Using XFree86 Acceleration Architecture (XAA)
[   343.672] (==) SAVAGE(0): Backing store disabled
[   343.672] (**) SAVAGE(0): DPMS enabled
[   343.673] (II) SAVAGE(0): [DRI] installation complete
[   343.676] (II) SAVAGE(0): Direct rendering enabled
```

From the log it looks like everything is correctly initialized. But still I have software rendering instead of HW accelerated. Of course, launching `glxgears` confirms that software rendering is being done, i.e. I get 0.68 FPS in fullscreen mode.

So my question is: is the support for HW acceleration on these chips completely thrown away by Mesa? Or do I have misconfiguration somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, old GPUs are unusable for OpenGL with modern Mesa releases. Their support has been dropped since 2012. Here's [the relevant mesa-dev thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2011-August/010959.html).

The first Mesa release without legacy drivers is [Mesa 8.0](http://mesa3d.org/relnotes/8.0.html).